# How identify generic button control in Excel table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have created an Excel sheet with a named table. On the left border of the first row I have added a button control labeled "+". This button runs a macro that always adds a new last row on the bottom of the table. Any new row also contains a copy of this button (although the button itself in Column A is not in the area of the named table).
Anyway, all these generic buttons do exactly the same.

Now, I want to add another button ("-") the same way, but this time I would like to REMOVE the line of the button I have clicked. To do this I have to identify the exact button that was clicked and find out the row where it is placed.

It looks like this:

[image]

Is this even possible and how?

**EDIT**:
To address the comments:

Code to add a new row at the end:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TimeSheetTable").Resize Range("$B$" & HEADERROW & ":$H$" & iNewRow)

'Duplicate the previous row
Rows(iNewRow- 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Rows(iNewRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Please post the code you already have for the addition.

Comment: If you are talking about the '-' sign on the button to remove, then it can change or delete by using the Caption Property of the Command button.

Comment: I'm truly surprised that, what for you are copy the Button after it adds row to the Table?

Comment: @RajeshS the button caption is not the issue here. its all about the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I would like to suggest you to use the following VBA Code. You need to call it with the Command Button you are suppose to identify was Clicked.*

```
Sub WhichOneClicked()

  Dim b As Object, iBtnRow As Integer
  Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)

  With b.TopLeftCell
    iBtnRow= .Row
  End With

 MsgBox "Row Number " & iBtnRow

End Sub
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Perfect solution, I modified it to get the ROW (which I need in this case).

Comment: Nice to here from you,, keep asking.

Answer (score 0):

*I've one more Solution which is much easier and strait forward identifies the Clicked Button. It has limited scope but is simple and easy to understand for ALL.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ButtonName
ButtonName = "CommandButton1"
MsgBox "You have clicked the " & ButtonName & " just now button."

End Sub
```

**NB:** Along with this code other VBA codes can be included or it can be called within the other code.

Comment: This would require to create own `Sub` for each button which doesn't seem feasible in this case as number of buttons is dynamic.